# View doesn't load JSON

Tags: json, symfony, twig

I'm working with Symfony 3, Angular JS and Twig. My problem comes when I try to generate a JSON in a view(html.twig).

**My Model (MongoDB)**

```
{                
                 "_id" : ObjectId("5a1feb783e06fa060c0076b2"),
                 "contenido" : [ 
                                  [
                                    {
                                        "type": "item",
                                        "name": "Foo",
                                        "id": 5
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "item",
                                        "name": "Bar",
                                        "id": 6
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
  class Controlador extends Controller
    {  
        // This method retrieve data (Document) from MongoDB
            public function renderizar(Request $request)
            { 
                ...
                $repository= $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                                  ->getManager()
                                  ->getRepository('AppBundle:Class');

                $object = $repository->find('5a1feb783e06dfa060c0076b2');

                $contenido = json_encode($object->getContenido()); 
                $contenidoB = htmlentities($contenido); 
                $contenidoC = html_entity_decode($contenidoB); 
                $contenidoDef = json_decode($contenidoC); 

                return $this->render('view.html.twig', 'contenido' => $contenidoDef));
            }
      }
```

I want to generate that JSON in the view (inside the AngularJS's controller) in order to render a drag and drop panel from AngularJS.

**My view**

```
        {% block body %}
            <!doctype html>
            <html >
            <head>
                <script>
                  angular.module("app").controller("NestedListsDemoController", function($scope)
                     {
                        $scope.models = {
                            dropzones: {
                                "A":  [
                                   {
                                    "type": "container",
                                    "name": "container",
                                    "id": 4,
                                    "columns": [
                                        [
                                            {
                                                "type": "item",
                                                "name": "Foo",
                                                "id": 5
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "item",
                                                "name": "Bar",
                                                "id": 6
                                            }
                                        ]
                                     ]
                                  }
                               ]
                            }
                        }; 
                    });

                </script>
            ...
       {% endblock %}
```

The Angular's controller doenst recognize the JSON in view if I use variable that contains that JSON.

```
 dropzones: {
             ...

               "A": {{ contenido|raw }}
            }
 or

 dropzones: {
               ...

                 "A": {{ contenido }}
            }
```

However, If I write the JSON in the view, it works. But I need to put the content from that variable. Any idea? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Pass regular php array to the view and apply these filters: dropzones = {{ contenido|json_encode|raw }};

Comment: As @SergeiKutanov explained, but just take a bit of extra precaution to avoid XSS. Data stored withing MongoDB could still contain `<script>` and as far as I saw, those would get executed.

Comment: The above applies if you want to print it anywhere outside of that struct, of course :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) @SergeiKutanov !

I am going to post the answer.

Comment: thank you also to @JovanPerovic . Can you show me an example Jovan? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the string I would received in controller. When I retreive the document from MongoDB (I don't know why) comes with an extra double **[ ]** . Then, the drag and drop panel didn't recognize that JSON format...

To solve, first I removed them in controller, secondly I generated the JSON in the view as follows:

```
dropzones: {
                    "A": [ {{ contenido|raw }} ]
           }
```

That's all, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
dropzones = {{ contenido|json_encode|raw }};
```